# Vertex of a parabola without calculus?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, quadratics, conic-sections

I am curious if there is a way to get the vertex of a parabola without calculus?

I know the calculus approach has you take the derivative set to $0$ (for $0$ slope) so if $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$ then $f'(x) = 2x + b$ so $0 = 2x + b$ implies $x = -\frac{b}{2a}$ with $y$ coordinate $f(-\frac{b}{2a})$.

But how would we get the vertex without calculus?

Comment: Complete the square.

Comment: Use the geometric definition of the parabola as a locus, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola#Axis_of_symmetry_parallel_to_the_y-axis) for example.

Comment: Try to find a point where for a particular y-value there exists exactly one x-value.

Answer (score 3):

You can observe that$$ax^2+bx+c=a\left(x^2+\frac bax+\frac ca\right)=a\left(\left(x+\frac b{2a}\right)^2+\frac ca-\frac{b^2}{4a^2}\right).$$So, the minimum or maximum is obtained when $x=-\frac b{2a}$.